# How to setup callback for mocked object method call by mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, callback, mockito

I have method and need to test it:

```
void update() {
    _cleaner.clear();
    _updator.upadate();
}
```

The ordering of calls is important for this scenario. I want to write test like this:

```
void updateTest(){

   Integer CLEAR = 0, UPDATE = 1;
   Stack<Integer> callStack = new Stack<>();

   Cleaner cleaner = mock(Cleaner.class);
   Updator updator = mock(Updator.class);

   when(cleaner.clear()).callback(() -> callStack.add(CLEAR)); 
   when(updator.update()).callback(() -> callStack.add(UPDATE));

   Some testingObj = new Some(cleaner, updator);
   testingObj.update();

   assertEquels(CLEAR, callStack.pop());
   assertEquels(UPDATE, callStack.pop());
   assertTrue(callStack.isEmpty());
}
```

_cleaner.clear() and _updator.upadate() returns void. It is clear that

```
when(cleaner.clear()).callback(() -> callStack.add(ClearCall)); 
when(updator.update()).callback(() -> callStack.add(UpdateCall));
```

is invalid code. What can I write except those lines for success? How to setup callback for method (with void as type of result) call by mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the `InOrder` verifier to confirm that the methods are called in the order you want. See here for some of the documentation: http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InOrder.html

This example is based on code straight from that documentation:

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(cleaner, updator);

inOrder.verify(cleaner).clear();
inOrder.verify(updator).update();
```